# MASM vector like array dynamic allocation

Tags: memory, assembly, masm, heapalloc

I need help with my MASM code. When I'm using dynamic allocation for arrays my other variables change values after adding few elements to array.

```
.686 
.387
.model flat, stdcall 
.xmm

include include\kernel32.inc
includelib lib\kernel32.lib

.data

szyfr DB 9, 15, 19, 2
;tab DD 4 dup (?)   - it works fine
;wynik DD 4 dup (?)   - it works fine

tmp DD 0
j DD 0
t DD 0
x DD 2
tmpa DD 0
tmpb DD 0
dlText DD 0
tab DD ?
wynik DD ?

.code
invoke GetProcessHeap
mov ebx, eax
INVOKE HeapAlloc, ebx, 0,  4      - it doesn't work
mov tab, eax
INVOKE HeapAlloc, ebx, 0,  4      - it doesn't work
mov wynik, eax
```

Writing to array:

```
xor edx, edx                
mov eax, esi                    ; esi = iterator = i        
mul x                           ; x = 2
mov edx, eax            
add edx, j                  
add edx, offset tab         
mov eax, t                      ; t = number <0, 26>
mov dword ptr [edx], eax        ; tab[i][j] = number <0, 26>
```

Comment: You haven't shown us how you actually write anything to the memory you allocated.

Comment: By the way, `DD 4 dup(?)` reserves space for 4 DWORDs. `HeapAlloc,ebx,0,4` allocates 4 _bytes_, i.e. _one_ DWORD.

Comment: @Michael Updated my question, I have tried with HeapAlloc,ebx,0, 100 or even bigger, but it changes nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method of accessing the memory you've allocated with `HeapAlloc` is incorrect. When you do `add edx, offset tab` you don't get the address of the memory you allocated; you get the address of `tab`, and `tab` is just a `DWORD`. To add the address of your allocated memory you should use `add edx,tab`.

---

By the way, these lines:

```
xor edx, edx                
mov eax, esi                    ; esi = iterator = i        
mul x                           ; x = 2
mov edx, eax
```

could be simplified into just:

```
lea edx,[esi*2]
```